# IIS7 ban IP range

Tags: iis-7, ip, spam, ip-blocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

I have a list of IP ranges I would like to ban, an example being:

119.30.47.xx

Where `xx` is anything.

I've added the domain and IP restrictions into IIS.  When I click add deny entry, I see:

[image]

For my above example, what should I enter as the values?

Comment: See [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](http://serverfault.com/q/49765/126632)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IP Address Range: 119.30.47.0
Mask or Prefix: 255.255.255.0

Other examples:

Ban the lower half: 119.30.47.1 - 119.30.47.127

IP Address Range: 119.30.47.0
Mask or Prefix: 255.255.255.128

Ban the upper half: 119.30.47.128 - 119.30.47.254

IP Address Range: 119.30.47.128
Mask or Prefix: 255.255.255.128

In last two examples, the mask 255.255.255.128 is also known as a "/25", because 25 of the first 32 bits of the address are part of the network address, and the remaining 7 bits are used for host addresses.

Probably a good idea to read up on subnetting, if you need to have a thorough understanding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnetting

Or use an online calculator.  This one is fairly decent:

http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators.php

Comment: The mask/prefix confuses me, should it always be `255.255.255.0`?

Comment: No, it would depend on the scope of addresses that you wanted to ban.  I will insert a few more examples.

Answer (score 3):

IP address range: 119.30.47.0

Mask or Prefix: 255.255.255.0